# Insert multiple rows in 2 tables using PDO and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to insert 3 rows in table dictionary and another 3 rows in table banner, so in this example I left only 1 query for each table.
the error I'm getting is

> Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

```
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', 'tiger');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->beginTransaction();

$conn->exec("INSERT INTO `dictionary` (`id`, `it`, `en`, `fr`, `es`, `pt`, `de`, `nl`) VALUES ('1', 'Sed tempus libero a tristique placerat.\r\n', 'Curabitur at justo sit amet mi aliquam vestibulum.\r\n', 'Duis sed elit suscipit, venenatis ipsum vitae, molestie elit.\r\n', 'Ut ac tortor semper, finibus est ac, porta erat.\r\n', 'Morbi sit amet quam facilisis, tristique mi a, sagittis quam.\r\n', 'Nulla nec sem quis velit tristique tempus vel id augue.\r\n', 'Mauris tincidunt leo eget tincidunt bibendum.\r\n')");
echo "New dictionary created successfully";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `banner` (`id`, `dictionaryId`, `name`, `destinationURL`, `domains`, `imageURL`, `position`, `startDate`, `finishDate`) VALUES ('5', '1', 'blink', 'github.com', 'Github', :imageURL, '5', '2019-04-18 03:00:00', '2019-05-04 00:00:00')");
$stmt->bindValue(':imageURL', $dropboxLink);
$stmt->execute();
$conn->commit();
echo "New banner created successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $stmt . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

Comment: `echo $stmt` expects `$stmt` to be a string, or to be convertable to a string. Since it is a `PDOStatement`, it is not. Change it to: `echo print_r($stmt, true)`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I commented echo in the catch error and still doesn't work

Comment: Just remember for your next question: Saying: "it doesn't work", gives very little information. Always tell us what the error messages are, and if they stay the same you should also tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified code, try this

```
try {
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', 'tiger');
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $conn->beginTransaction();

  $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `dictionary` (`id`, `it`, `en`, `fr`, `es`, `pt`, `de`, `nl`) VALUES ('1', 'Sed tempus libero a tristique placerat.\r\n', 'Curabitur at justo sit amet mi aliquam vestibulum.\r\n', 'Duis sed elit suscipit, venenatis ipsum vitae, molestie elit.\r\n', 'Ut ac tortor semper, finibus est ac, porta erat.\r\n', 'Morbi sit amet quam facilisis, tristique mi a, sagittis quam.\r\n', 'Nulla nec sem quis velit tristique tempus vel id augue.\r\n', 'Mauris tincidunt leo eget tincidunt bibendum.\r\n')");
  $stmt1->execute();
  echo "New dictionary created successfully";

  $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `banner` (`id`, `dictionaryId`, `name`, `destinationURL`, `domains`, `imageURL`, `position`, `startDate`, `finishDate`) VALUES ('5', '1', 'blink', 'github.com', 'Github', :imageURL, '5', '2019-04-18 03:00:00', '2019-05-04 00:00:00')");
  $stmt2->bindValue(':imageURL', $dropboxLink);
  $stmt2->execute();
  $conn->commit();
  echo "New banner created successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```